localhost didn't send any data -pgAdmin
Can help me ,I cant go to the docker pgAdmin
Where i go to http://localhost:5050/  I get localhost didn't send any data.Maybe problem in my yml file.Can say me what i can do to it will work
My yml file
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped


networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:

docker compose ps
    D:\Java\Spring\microservicesguide>docker compose ps
NAME       IMAGE            COMMAND                  SERVICE    CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
pgadmin    dpage/pgadmin4   "/entrypoint.sh"         pgadmin    19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp
postgres   postgres         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   postgres   19 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp

I try off firewall it doesnt help.

You are setting the por for pgadmin inside the container to port 5050. But you then map the port 5050 outside the container to port 80 inside the container. But nothing it listening on port 80 now. Either updated your port mapping to 5050:5050 or remove the pgadmin listen port env var so it will listen on port 80
